# Appium chrome click not working

Tags: node.js, selenium, appium

I use wd to test on mobile web page using Chrome but it seem that click on the page do nothing but click directly on the Android simulator working as expected. Log as the following:

```
> CALL elementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/a")
> POST /session/:sessionID/element
> {"using":"xpath","value":"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/a"}
> RESPONSE
> elementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/a")
> {"ELEMENT":"0.5510012301289775-4"} CALL element.click() POST
> /session/:sessionID/element/0.5510012301289775-4/click RESPONSE
> element.click()
```

More info: the element is on the bottom of the page so I must called scroll before clicking; so the problem is call `click()` on the element not on the view of screen. It seem to have trouble with the page with height longer than the page on Appium - Android(Chrome)

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Give some wait time before clicking any element and try. I also faced the same problem before page load completely driver tries to click on the element. So clicking is performed on some other element in the page.

Comment: Wait time not working here @@ if I try to call to calling by `driver.evalScript("arguments[0].click()", element)` it works well.